# optimal arrangement of fixed length unlimited items and their segments on a fixed length space

Tags: algorithm

We have the following WALL measurements:
a)3.60 meters
b)4.20 meters
c)2.80 meters
d)0.75 meters
I also have known legths of COMPONENTS
a)2 meters
b)3 meters
We can cut these components to whatever legths we want (SEGMENTS).

Our goal is to find the optimal number of components and segemts to use to fill all the walls.

Let's look at a simple example to solve this problem:

wall a)3.60 meters can be divided into
-- 1 segment of 3 meters and
-- a segment of 0.60 meters (from the smallest component 2 meters).
wall b)4.20 meters can be divided into
-- 1 segment of 3 meters and
-- a segment of 1.20 meters (we can use the part from wall a).

wall c)2.80 meters can be divided into
-- 1 component of 2 meters and
--  a leftover of 1.80 meters (a new cut of a 2meter component).
wall d)0.75 we can use the part from wall a

Component: a length of material that will be cut into smaller pieces
Cut: a length of material that has been cut from stock. multiple cuts may be taken from the same piece of stock
Waste: the length of material that is left in a piece of stock after all cuts have been made.
We are trying to minimise the waste not the bins.

Note that we have unlimited items and unlimited ways to cut them in segments.

We need help on figuring out the algorithm of this.

we did not try to create an algorithm that creates combinations. we just started adding the biggest components first
then we trying to adding the segments by just substracting the nearest component length to the wall leftover space.
this does not produce all the possible correct answers

Comment: ✏️This is an assignment. In order for us to assist please show us **what you tried** and try and articulate where you're having problems with your understanding of the requirements and/or your code.

Comment: If you are not penalized for cutting components, it boils down to making up the combined wall length. Since component lengths are mutually prime, you can make up any length with increments of 1 meter. So, round up the combined wall length (that's the best you can do), fill it with 3-meter components, cut excess by replacing 3 by 2 or 2x2 by 3

Comment: i am trying to create a generic line segmentation algorithm. This is just an example i posted. This is not an assigment. I will write as much as i can about my algorithm in the following days.
There are no penalties for cutting components.